# Нужна ли запятая перед "или"? (1)

Tags: пунктуация, или

> Где должна размещаться электронная версия годового отчета: на главной корпоративной веб-странице или на отдельном микросайте?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Мы имеем дело с двумя версиями вопроса (оригинальной и исправленной), которые, по мнению некоторых участников, идентичны с точки зрения постановки запятой. Я с этим мнением не согласен. Думаю, столь радикальная правка без согласования с автором вопроса не должна иметь место.

На вторую версию вопроса (**Где должна размещаться электронная версия годового отчета: на главной корпоративной веб-странице или на отдельном микросайте?**)  ответили другие участники, и я с ними согласен: запятая  не нужна.

А вот первая версия (**Вопрос, который в последние годы разделил специалистов сферы корпоративных коммуникаций на два лагеря: должна ли электронная версия годового отчета размещаться на главной корпоративной веб-странице(,) или на отдельном микросайте?**) требует, по-моему, постановки запятой, потому что пара *ли* и *или* должна рассматриваться как повторяющийся союз.

Дополнение.

По-моему, оригинальная версия построена неудачно, в разговорном стиле. Ее стоило бы исправить:

**Вопрос, который в последние годы разделил специалистов сферы корпоративных коммуникаций на два лагеря: электронная версия годового отчета должна размещаться на главной корпоративной веб-странице или на отдельном микросайте?**

Тогда и запятая не нужна.

А еще лучше так:

**Вопрос, который в последние годы разделил специалистов сферы корпоративных коммуникаций на два лагеря: где должна размещаться электронная версия годового отчета — на главной корпоративной веб-странице или на отдельном микросайте?**

Я поставил тире после слова *отчета*, чтобы избежать повторения двоеточия. Но тут, мне кажется, возможны варианты, и их стоило бы обсудить. Постановка знака вопроса тоже кажется мне опциональной, и это стоило бы обсудить.

Comment: _Думаю, столь радикальная правка без согласования с автором вопроса не должна иметь место._ Абсолютно согласна с Вами. Я ещё вчера в своём комментарии попыталась заострить на этом внимание. Но слова "Римма Михайлова переживает о пропаже первой части авторской фразы" отбили у меня всякое желание спорить. Ваш статус выше, у Вас опыта больше.

Comment: Вместе мы сила :)

Answer (score 2):

Если однородные члены предложения соединены одиночным разделительным союзом [или], то запятую перед союзом ставить не нужно:
**должна размещаться** (где?) *на веб-странице* или (где?) *на микросайте*.
("На главной корпоративной веб-странице" и "на отдельном микросайте" — однородные распространенные обстоятельства.)
[**Однородные члены предложения**](http://gramota.ru/class/coach/punct/45_190)

В Вашем предложении запятая перед "или" не нужна.

Answer (score 0):

Запятая здесь совершенно не нужна.

Comment: Запятая здесь совершенно не нужна, ибо...

Comment: Я посчитала, что это единое, полное авторское предложение _Вопрос, который в последние годы разделил специалистов сферы корпоративных коммуникаций на два лагеря: должна ли электронная версия годового отчета размещаться на главной корпоративной веб-странице, или на отдельном микросайте?_  После двух правок первичное предложение стало совсем другим.

Comment: @shampar ведь никто не должен объяснять, почему не нужно знаков препинания! Надо обосновывать только их постановку.

Comment: @РиммаМихайлова я изменил, п. ч. звучало странно, на мой взгляд.  Если вначале "должно ли...", то продолжением может быть, по-моему, только другой полноценный вопрос, выражающий принципиально другой вариант и содержащий свои подлежащее и сказуемое. А вопрос "или на" скорее предполагает общее начало "где".

Comment: @Артём Луговой, отвечу словами из Справки: Не стоит отвечать просто «не делай этого»...Возможен и краткий ответ, но чем подробнее и понятнее он будет изложен, тем лучше.

Comment: РиммаМихайлова переживает о пропаже первой части авторской фразы. Я же увидел там только множество буковок, перевешивающих объём второй части и к сути вопроса не относящихся.

Comment: @shampar дело в том, что я вторую часть изменил, прежде чем Вы убрали первую. Скорее, она из-за этого всё-таки переживала. Полностью согласен с Вашим первым комментарием, что лучше подробнее и понятнее, но мне гораздо проще возразить на мысли в пользу запятой, чем самому придумывать ей мнимые обоснования и их опровергать. А так, Римма Михайлова всё правильно сказала. Просто мне надо было бы долго думать, чтобы это так сформулировать.

Comment: Спасибо за поддержку — доброе слово и иностранке приятно.

Comment: Конечно! Иностранка тоже человек.))))